# Pandas combine columns values into cells of a row by type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Ive got this dataframe

```
ID  type    name    number  description comments
1   short   A       2       XX          xxx
1   short   B                               
1   short   C       4       YY          yyy
1   full    A/B/C
2   short   E       
2   short   F       9       ZZ          zzz                     
2   short   G       7       WW          www
2   short   H       
2   full    E/F/G/H
```

And I want to transform it into by collapsing in `type full` rows the `number`, `description` and `comments` columns values (if they exists) in `type short` rows

```
id  type    name    number  description comments
1   full    A/B/C   2/4     XX/YY       xxx/yyy
2   full    E/F/G/H 9/7     ZZ/WW       zzz/www
```

I tried it using aggregation and groupby functions but without success.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic dictionary by `dict.fromkeys` with lambda function for all columns without `id` and keys from dictionary `d1` and pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
f = lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().astype(str))

d1 = {'type':'last', 'name':'last'}
d2 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['id'] + list(d1.keys())), f)
d = {**d1, **d2}    

df = df.groupby('id', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df)
   id  type     name comments description   number
0   1  full    A/B/C  xxx/yyy       XX/YY  2.0/4.0
1   2  full  E/F/G/H  zzz/www       ZZ/WW  9.0/7.0
```

If need processes values in lambda function by types - e.g. sum of numeric and join by non numeric columns:

```
f = lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else '/'.join(x.dropna())

d1 = {'type':'last', 'name':'last'}
d2 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['id'] + list(d1.keys())), f)
d = {**d1, **d2}           
df = df.groupby('id', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df)
   id  type     name comments description  number
0   1  full    A/B/C  xxx/yyy       XX/YY     6.0
1   2  full  E/F/G/H  zzz/www       ZZ/WW    16.0
```

Comment: I am gonna try it @jezrael. But how would it be the agg dictionary if I have much more columns???

Comment: @Solar - `this is not showing the type full rows` - Can you explain more?